# Node template engine that can include other templates?

Tags: node.js, templates, express

Starting to get into node but struggling to pick a template engine..

Is there an engine out there that can include other templates in the same twig can?

[EG](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html):

```
{% include 'template.html' with {'foo': 'bar'} %}
```

Comment: If you're looking to set a general common page format (headers/footers, etc.) with each page having custom content, Jade will do that (I've used it on a project and liked it Ok...). If you're looking for page fragments a la java server pages that can be inserted anywhere in another page... jQuery has some options - (haven't used any on a project, so can't comment..)

Comment: Ok cool i will take a look.. I did look at jade but the syntax was a little funky. Would you recommend ejs?

Comment: EJS is what I use now, exactly because of Jade's funkiness (and lack of good docs - at least when I was trying it out). Plus, coming from a Java/C# asp.net background, the conventions were immediately familiar.

Comment: I think ejs it is then. Thanks,  John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with this in the end:
http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/

I is a port of twig to js.. absolutely awesome and does exactly what you would expect from a twig.

UPDATE: It swig ha since been deprecated in favor of:
https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/

Answer (score 0):

I recommend a new template engine: Saker, it enables fluid coding workflow, unlike most template syntaxes, you do not need to interrupt your coding to explicitly denote server blocks within your HTML.
Saker is my personal open source project.
Github: https://github.com/eshengsky/saker

Comment: @MartijnPieters got it!